# Error opening excel workbook, programs stops responding

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I am unable to open `xml` workbook because there is an code by the name of `workbook_open` or `Auto_open` which runs on opening the workbook.

Is there a way I can recover the code from my workbook?

Microsoft Excel asks for whether to wait for the program to retstart, close the program.

Comment: Please provide more detail to your question.  What error message do you get?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your `workbook_open` has a code that somehow closes the file or destroys it in some way. What you can do is clear trusted documents with the following steps.

In excel go to file > options > trust center > trust center settings > trusted documents

Then clear all trusted documents.

The next time when you open your workbook macros will not be enabled by default, so the `workbook_open` will not be triggered so instead of enabling it simply view the macros by pressing alt+F11

Answer (score 0):

Rename the workbook then open it.

Don't allow / enable macros when the security dialogue pops up.

Press Alt + F11 to enter the VBA IDE.

In the project explorer find your project.

Find your worksheet in the project explorer, double click on it.

Delete any code there and save.